# jquery extend returns init function

Tags: jquery

Is this a bug?

```
var x = $.extend({});
var y = $.extend({},{});

alert($.isEmptyObject(y)); //true as expected
alert($.isEmptyObject(x)); //false?
```

If not, why is this the expected behavior and why is it not documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually is documented in the [docs for `extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

> If only one argument is supplied to $.extend(), this means the target argument was omitted. In this case, the jQuery object itself is assumed to be the target. By doing this, you can add new functions to the jQuery namespace. This can be useful for plugin authors wishing to add new methods to JQuery.

So, `x` is actually extending the `jQuery` object, which of course includes all of its normal functions including init.

Comment: ok, ignore me then... I've actually used that functionality. will accept asap.